# git cherry-pick top from dirty branch

Tags: git

I made some experiments in master (I know It wasn't good idea), and than checkout my `feature branch`. Later them I dropped old "dirty" master and recreated new one. Now I want to cherry-pick jst top commit (that only relates to developed feature) into new "clean" master.

But cherry-pick grabs additional commits, out of specified range, that was earlier on old master. How can one handle this?

```
o---o---o---o---o  old dirty master
    |            \
    |             o'--o'--o'  feature branch
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  clean master
```

Comment: Did you give the exact commit ID you wanted? e.g. `git cherry-pick abc123`

Comment: I have range of them, last n commits

Comment: Maybe provide the exact command you used.  You should just be able to cherry pick one specific commit as @CoryKramer suggests.